# How send Geoserver WMS GetFeatureInfo query to an area

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo, openlayers

I am using GetFeatureInfo query to WMS service. When I click a WMS object on the map, the response is coming.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?
request=GetFeatureInfo
&service=WMS
&version=1.1.1
&layers=topp%3Astates
&styles=
&srs=EPSG%3A4326
&format=image%2Fpng
&bbox=-145.151041%2C21.73192%2C-57.154894%2C58.961059
&width=780
&height=330
&query_layers=topp%3Astates
&info_format=text%2Fhtml
&feature_count=50
&x=353
&y=145
&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml
```

But I want to send a request a polygonal area. Not a single x,y location. How can I do this? Is possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can only use a x,y (i,j) coordinate search for GetFeatureInfo requests
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo

However, you may test for interactions with polygons (and many other geometries) using a Web Feature Service (WFS) request.

E.g. https://wiki.state.ma.us/confluence/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+WFS+-+Get+Feature+by+Polygon+-+Other+Projection

Comment: GetFeatureInfo actually takes only a point (x,y) or (i,j). You can buffer the point into a circle with the buffer vendor option http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html?highlight=getfeatureinfo#buffer. For polygon, use WFS and Intersects filter as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a request for features is done on a featureservice (WFS) - esp. when you have a more complex logic like querying features within a given polygon. The GetFeatureInfo is designed to perform a feature-query based on the mouse-position in native (meaning display-) coordinates rather the geographic (transformed) coords. But it is indeed restricted to that single position (don´t get irritated: the BBOX param is the parameter for the map-size itself, it has nothing to do with your actual feature-query). If you have a GeoServer you may have a look at [WMS reference](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html) also, but also if you don´t (the site deals for WebServices in general, no matter if GeoServer or not).

Answer (score 0):

With Geoserver you might want to have a try with the CQL filters which are much easier to write than the official OGC style XML/GML filters.

I took the "DISJOINT" example from the manual http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html and converted into WFS GetFeature request with INTERSECTS filter. You can test it with the demo server of Boundless with this request

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(the_geom, POLYGON((-90 40, -90 45, -60 45, -60 40, -90 40)))